# AddAll itens em comboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

Eu tenho um `ComboBox`, e estou tentando colocar itens (valores strings) porém ele não esta aceitando.

Eu fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
private ComboBox<?> meuCombo;

public void combos() {
    meuCombo.getItems().addAll("A", "B");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe que o método `getItems()` do comboBox retorna um *ObservableList*. Porque você não tenta setar manualmente o *ObservableList* do seu *ComboBox*, dessa forma:

```
private ComboBox<String> meuCombo;

public void combos(){
    ObservableList<String> itens = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    itens.addAll("A", "B");

    meuCombo.setItems(list)
}
```

Não vi no seu código como você instanciou seu ComboBox mas você pode passar o *ObservableList* como argumento dessa forma: `meuCombo = new ComboBox(itens)`.